# error:Spell checkig is unavalable: No word list can be found for the language "es-ES"

Tags: linux, git

He instalado Git Gui Gitk en LinuxMint. Al ejecutar git-gui, obtengo el error "Spell checkig is unavalable: No word list can be found for the language "es-ES". Cómo puedo fijar este error?.

Comment: Tu sistema esta en el formato es-ES y básicamente te dice que la revisión ortográfica no se encuentra disponible porque no encuentra el paquete ortográfico para ese idioma, prueba instalándolo desactivando la revisión ortográfica.

Comment: Pero ¿cómo se desactiva la revisión ortográfica en LinuxMint?. Busco en Internet y encuentro para Libre Office, etc. pero no para el SO

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es compilarlo desde el fuente, o utilizar otra GUI, puedes utilizar varias, puedes mirarlas [aquí](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux).